# Google Maps v3 only displaying grey box

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been building a google maps integration into my site, and the code I have works perfectly in just a plain html page on its own, but when I put it in the website it is intended for, all that appears is a grey box, with `map` and `satellite` buttons at the top, and the google logo with `map data` and `terms of use` at the bottom. The navigation buttons don't come up (zoom, move and street view). Does anyone know what could be causing it?

This is the code i'm using:
http://jsfiddle.net/kd7dX/

Comment: works on ff 11 after copy & paste from jsfiddle into html document. Check on other browsers , inspect console and network tab in developer tool (opera,chrome) or in firebug look for js errors

Comment: Well that Fiddle works beautifully, so it must be something else. Are you creating a hidden map and then revealing it?

Comment: works in all browsers, just not on my site

Comment: @AndrewLeach Nope, there are no extra styles being applied to or scripts manipulating it

Comment: Can't help with something that works, though. You'll need to provide something which demonstrates the failure.

Comment: When it  *works in all browsers, just not on my site* , you should show us your site.

Comment: can't, got a NDA, but i'll get you a screen shot

Comment: Can't debug a screen shot (and anyway, you've described it: the map is grey). Put some code together which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Aha, found the issue, its an `overflow: hidden` rule in the css applied to all div's. What an irritating thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using CSS Rule:

```
div {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

replaced with a more targeted overflow rule